# filter through js objects using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, filter

I am trying to filter through this javascript object using underscore.js, but I don't know why it's not working, its meant to find any question value that has "how" in it.

```
  var questions = [
    {question: "what is your name"},
    {question: "How old are you"},
    {question: "whats is your mothers name"},
    {question: "where do work/or study"},
    ];

var match = _.filter(questions),function(words){ return words === "how"});

alert(match); // its mean to print out -> how old are you?
```

the full code is here(underscore.js already included): http://jsfiddle.net/7cFbk/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. You closed the function call with `.filter(questions)`. The last `)` shouldn't be there.
2. Filtering works by iterating over the array and calling the function with each element. Here, each element is an object `{question: "..."}`, not a string.
3. You check for equality, whereas you want to check whether the question string *contains* a certain string. You even want it case-insensitive.
4. You cannot alert objects. Use the console and `console.log` instead.

So: http://jsfiddle.net/7cFbk/45/

```
var questions = [
    {question: "what is your name"},
    {question: "How old are you"},
    {question: "whats is your mothers name"},
    {question: "where do work/or study"},
];

var evens = _.filter(questions, function(obj) {
    // `~` with `indexOf` means "contains"
    // `toLowerCase` to discard case of question string
    return ~obj.question.toLowerCase().indexOf("how");
});

console.log(evens);
```

Comment: thanks works very good, how can pass these values into a html element, adding them to a div i.e. `foreach question found $('divname').html('<p>' + even.obj + '<p>');` thanks :)

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit. But you'll need `_.each` I think.

Comment: To others new to Javascript, and didn't quite catch the comment in the example, the '~' at the beggining of the return line is important and the full line is equivalent to "obj.question.toLowerCase().indexOf("how") >= 0" in this specific case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working version:

```
var questions = [
    {question: "what is your name"},
    {question: "How old are you"},
    {question: "whats is your mothers name"},
    {question: "where do work/or study"},
];

var hasHow = _.filter(questions, function(q){return q.question.match(/how/i)});

console.log(hasHow);
```

#### issues fixed:

- Parens were not correctly placed.
- Use `console.log` instead of alert.
- You should probably use a regexp to find 'how' when iterating over each question.
- `_filter` iterates over an array. Your array contains objects, and each object contains a question. The function you pass to `_filter` needs to examine each object in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
    'data1' :{
        'name':'chicken noodle'
     },
    'data2' :{
        'name':'you must google everything'
     },
    'data3' :{
        'name':'Love eating good food'
     }
}

_.filter(data,function(i){

    if(i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('chick') == 0){

        console.log(i);

    }else{

        console.log('error');

    }

})
```